# Counting values of one vector that lie in between the values of another vector

Tags: matlab, vector

Say we have two ascending sorted vectors:

```
V1 V2
12 13
15 16
25 17
29 28
```

What is the simplest way in Matlab to count how many values of `V2` fall between consecutive values of `V1`?

In this example the resulting vector should be:

```
Counts
1
2
1
```

since

```
1 - 13(V2) fits between 12-15(V1)

2 - 16 and 17(V2) fits between 15-25(V1)

1 - 28(V2) fits between 25-29(V1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't believe that nobody has thought of [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) yet:

```
count = histc(v2,v1);
```

gives, in this case

```
count =
     1 %// 1 value  of v2 is  >= v1(1) and < v1(2)
     2 %// 2 values of v2 are >= v1(2) and < v1(3)
     1 %// 1 value  of v2 is  >= v1(3) and < v1(4)
     0 %// 0 values of v2 are == v1(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works without loops:

```
V1 = [12 15 25 29]';
V2 = [13 16 17 28]';


V3 = [V1 zeros(size(V1)); V2 ones(size(V2))];
V4 = sortrows(V3);

ret = diff(find(V4(:,2)==0))-1
```

This first creates the Vector

```
V3 =

   12    0
   15    0
   25    0
   29    0
   13    1
   16    1
   17    1
   28    1
```

Then sorts it

```
V4 =

   12    0
   13    1
   15    0
   16    1
   17    1
   25    0
   28    1
   29    0
```

Now the position of the zeros mark the next entry in V1. `find` finds those positions and diff substracts the positions, leaving the numbers from V2 between them plus one.

Answer (score 1):

`bsxfun` can do all the tests you need, then you can vectorize the combination with `&` (element-wise AND), and sum:

```
>> low = bsxfun(@lt,V1,V2.');    %' each row of V1 < each row of V2
>> high = bsxfun(@gt,V1,V2.');   %' each row of V1 > each row of V2
>> sum(low(1:end-1,:) & high(2:end,:),2)
ans =
     1
     2
     1
```

NOTE: To check `>=` instead of `>`, use `@ge` (instead of `@gt`). Similarly for `<=` and `<`, use `@le` or `@lt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
>> v1 = [12    ;15    ;25    ;29];
>> v2 = [13    ;16    ;17    ;28];
>> diff(find(ismember(sort([v1 ;v2]),v1) == 1))  - 1
ans =

     1     
     2     
     1
```

magic!!  without loops!!

But the logic is quiet easy to understand

Using row vectors instead of column vectors as an example

I first create a sorted list of combination of v1, v2
so

```
>> v3 = sort([v1 v2])

v3 =

    12    13    15    16    17    25    28    29
```

Then this is the key step, I make members of v1 as 1 in v4 and the rest 0. Like this

```
>> v4 = ismember(v3,v1)

v4 =

     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     1
```

At this point, the problem is almost solved, I need to find the groups of zeros and thier length

```
>> diff(find(v4 == 1)) - 1

ans =

     1     2     1
```

No loops, less time to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
V1 = [12,15,25,29];
V2 = [13,16,17,28];
V3 = zeros(1,length(V1)-1);
count = 0;

for i = 1:length(V1)-1
    for k = 1:length(V2)
        if(V2(k)>V1(i) && V2(k)<V1(i+1))
            count = count+1;
        end

    end
    V3(i) = count;
    count = 0;
end

V3
```